# Jenkins MsBuild.exe issue

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins, msbuild-task

I'm using Jenkins 2.7.2 installed as a Windows service via the Windows Installer. Jenkins installed in my local PC only.  I do not see anything in Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System having to do with MSBuild. I've installed the MSBuild plugin, but don't see it in configure Jenkins. Is this a bug in 2.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find this MsBuild section into Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration.

Looks like it moved here with Jenkins 2